# What are the sleeping needs of the various Star Trek species?

Tags: star-trek

Humans in the Star Trek universe are like humans today---in general, they require about 7-9 hours of sleep per night to function adequately the next day.

Is there any mention of the sleep needs of other races---Vulcans, Klingons, Gorn, Ferengi, augmented humans (Dr. Bashir, Khan), etc.?

Comment: There are way too many species in Star Trek. Please elaborate on which of them you would like the information.

Answer (score 14):

### Memory-Alpha does have a page on [Sleep](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Sleep).

**Vulcans** can go up to two weeks without sleep. *VOY: "Muse"*

[Dr. Phlox](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Phlox) (a **Denobulan**) requires very little sleep each night (or none at all), but does have a long hybernation period for 5-6 days once a year. *ENT: "Dear Doctor", "Two Days and Two Nights", "Similitude"*

**Changlings** (or at least [Odo](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Odo)) had to revert to a gelatinous state every 16 hours, as he was unable to hold a solid form for much longer. *DS9: "The Forsaken"*

**[Tosk](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Tosk)** seems to only require seventeen minutes of sleep each *rotation*(whatever that is). *DS9: "Captive Pursuit"*

Neither the **[Jem'Hadar](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Jem%27Hadar)** nor **[Species 8472](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Species_8472)** require any sleep. *DS9: "To the Death"* *VOY: "Scorpion", "Scorpion, Part II"*

Comment: I wonder if space creatures, like the Crystalline Entity, Tin Man, and others, require some sort of "sleep."

Answer (score 6):

## Vulcans

In the *TOS* episode ["The Paradise Syndrome"](http://www.chakoteya.net/StarTrek/58.htm), Spock claims:

> I am not hungry, Doctor. And under stress, we Vulcans can do without sleep for weeks.

In *Voyager* ["Muse"](http://www.chakoteya.net/Voyager/623.htm), Tuvok says something similar:

> As a Vulcan, I can function without sleep for more than two weeks.

Although this doesn't give a number of hours, I feel it is relevant to your concern about "functioning adequately" — it suggests that Vulcans can function adequately without any sleep for a number of days before seeing any subsequent decline in their performance.

## Odo

Also, while not sleep exactly, Odo must return to a liquid state every **16-18 hours** — a fact which is regularly repeated in *DS9*.  It is unclear, however, if this extends to the rest of the Changelings (many of whom have superior shapeshifting skills).

When he's deprived of his down time, he doesn't function very adequately:

[image]

Comment: I feel like that if I nap during the day...

Comment: If Vulcans can go several days or even a couple of weeks without sleeping, I find it doubtful that they sleep 7-9 hours in any given night. Unless they're particularly exhausted from a hard day or whatever.

Comment: @T-1000'sSon : They probably meditate more than they sleep --- Tuvok spends considerable time meditating.

Comment: Yeah, that probably takes up a lot of their "rest." Though obviously they need literal sleep, too.

Comment: @T-1000'sSon : There are instances of Tuvok sleeping, such as when they were being attacked in their sleep by a species that communicates through dreams.  (Tuvok had a nightmare where he walked onto the bridge naked.)